# How to get the page object from a Capybara::Session object

Tags: selenium, webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to use capybara's method page.should have_content("some txt").

I use capybara by getting a capybara session, but can't figure out how to get the page object

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
capdriver = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
capdriver.visit ("https://google.com")
```

How to use this using the active session (capdriver) from above:

```
page.should have_content("some google text")
```

I might be setting up capybara wrong (I'm used to using Selenium::Webdriver directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page` is just a method, defined on Capybara::DSL, that returns Capybara.current_session when you have included Capybara::DSL into your test class when using Capybaras automatic session management.  Since you're manually managing sessions you already have access to the Capybara::Session object you want to assert against, so

```
capdriver.should have_content("some google text")
```

Note, this assumes you have included Capybara::RSpecMatchers into whatever object scope you're running this in (so `have_content` is available)

Comment: I've tried this and I get a 'NoMethod' error (I did have require 'capybara/rspec' - I'm assuming this included the RSpecMatchers ??)
   NoMethodError:
       undefined method `have_content' for #<SetPassword:0x007fb6dfa68298 @webdriver=#<Capybara::Session>>

Comment: Requiring capybara/rspec includes the matchers into rspec view and feature specs - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L10 - so unless you're in a view or feature example (scenario/it block) then it's not included.  From the error it looks like you're running it inside an instance of the `SetPassword` class, is that an RSpec test instance? If it is then make sure it's tagged with `type: :feature` or `type: :view` depending on what type of test it is.